# Get the location of a flash button

Tags: flash, selenium-webdriver, awtrobot

I have a flash button in my site,

```
<object id="p17p316lo71o2j_flash" width="100%" height="100%" style="outline:0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://testsite.com/includes/plupload/.../js/plupload.flash.swf"><param name="movie" value="http://testsite.com/includes/plupload/.../js/plupload.flash.swf"><param name="flashvars" value="id=p17p316lo71o2j"><param name="wmode" value="transparent"><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></object>`
```

is it possible to get the flash object location (x,y) so that i can point that to the java robot to click on it .. ? can anyone help me on this .. im using Selenium Webdriver Java - TestNG ..

Thanks in Advance ..

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible to get not only its location, but also its size. For instance, in Java you can get the coordinates and size of every flash object with this code:

```
listFlash = _driver.findElements(By.xpath("//object[@type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\"]"));
for (WebElement flash: listFlash)
{
    System.out.println("Coordinates: " + flash.getLocation().x + ", " + flash.getLocation().y);
    System.out.println("Size: " + flash.getSize().width + ", " + flash.getSize().height);
}
```

Comment: It worked for me with an actual page with dozens of flash objects of different sizes. If you have any problem, post an answer with your code and log messages, so we can find a solution.